# Running shell commands in GVim without echoing the Vim command

Tags: shell, vim

When I use `:!` to run shell commands, like:

```
!echo hi
```

It prints both the VimScript command and it's output, so I get:

```
:!echo hi
hi
```

This is OK when I do it in command line mode, but when I run it via a `.vim` file I don't want to see it - I just want to see the result of the command.

Is there a way to disable the echoing of the VimScript command?

I know I can use

```
echo system('echo hi')
```

But that would prevent me from using it with interactive shell programs...

BTW, I'm using Linux - in windows this is not really a problem since shell commands run on a new console window anyways...

**edit**:

This is my small working example:

```
function! RunShellTask(cmd)
    execute '!'.a:cmd
    return v:shell_error
endfunction

call RunShellTask('echo hi')
```

I run it with `:source %`

Comment: How are you executing the `.vim` file?

Comment: @vidit See update to question

Comment: @IdanArye are you in gvim? I don't see the command being outputted in the command line version

Comment: @FDinoff Yes, probably should have mentioned it. I'll update the question.

Comment: @IdanArye I think you shouldn't be using vim as an interactive shell. Its not meant to be one. Take a look at `:h shell-window`

Comment: @FDinoff I'm not trying to use Vim as an interactive shell. I'm trying to use Vim as a development environment(I hope it's allowed to use Vim as a development environment even thought it's a text editor...). And when I'm developing, I ofter need to run a an interactive shell program(for example - when I'm making one), or to run a program that shows it's output slowly(for example - `git push`). I don't want to use `echo system()` for this, because it'll freeze until it's done and then print everything instead of showing me the progress and prompting me to enter input.

Comment: @IdanArye it sounds like you are trying to use vim exactly like an interactive shell... If you are going to be using a lot of command line tools why don't you use vim in the command line? You can just run a different tab, shell, suspend vim, or use terminal multiplexer to test your program or run `git push`. As one user says a lot here "VIM in NOT an IDE"

Comment: @FDinoff I prefer GVim. I like how the cursor changes between normal and insert modes. I like that `Alt+` keymaps work. And I like to be able to run a shell without having the buffers I'm working on suddenly disappear. I don't care that "VIM is NOT and IDE" - I've been using it as a development environment for a few years and it's working pretty damn well so far.

Comment: Of course, vim is an IDE. It's even the best IDE around. However, I totally fail to understand why it's so terrible to have vim echo that first line.

Comment: @innaM It's not *terrible* - it's just a minor annoyance. I'm making a Vim plugin that allows you to configure "chores" for your project - like running your project with test input, opening a a shell and setting it to a certain state etc. Those chores will be running lot's of shell commands, and I prefer not to echo all those commands every time I run a chore.

Comment: OK. What is really interesting is the fact that gvim and vim behave differently in this respect. I wonder whether gvim has an option set that vim hasn't or whether this is compiled into gvim.

Comment: @innaM I think this has to do with how Vim and GVim execute shell commands. Vim runs in terminal, so when it has to run an external command, it switches back to terminal in order to run it. GVim, on the other hand, has to emulate the terminal(or, in case of Windows, open a new console window). Maybe Vim also echoes the vimscript command, but you can't see it since it goes full terminal to run the command.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `:redir` command:

```
                     *:redi* *:redir*
:redi[r][!] > {file} Redirect messages to file {file}.  The messages which
                     are the output of commands are written to that file,
                     until redirection ends.  The messages are also still
                     shown on the screen.  When [!] is included, an
                              :
                              :
                     To stop the messages and commands from being echoed to
                     the screen, put the commands in a function and call it
                     with ":silent call Function()".
                     An alternative is to use the 'verbosefile' option,
                     this can be used in combination with ":redir".
```

I haven't tested, but you could try `:redir @b`, execute the shell commands from a function called with `:silent call`, read the output (from register b), filter out the vimscript commands, display it on the screen and then `:redir end`.

Another option is to try some plugins that provide similar functionality:

- [shellasync.vim : shellasync.vim plugin for asynchronously executing shell commands in vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4182)
- [Conque Shell : Run interactive commands inside a Vim buffer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2771)
- [Screen (vim + gnu screen/tmux) : Simulate a split shell, using gnu screen or tmux, that you can send commands to.](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2711)
- [Vicle : Vim - Interpreter Command Line Editor. Like Chimp or Slimv.](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2551)

Comment: Thanks, but none of these really fit my purpose.

Comment: You mean the plugins? Did you try the procedure with `:redir`?

Comment: `:redir` does not help me, because the VimScript command is still echoed to the screen. As for the plugins - like I said, I'm not trying to run an interactive shell from Vim. When I do want it, I prefer [VimShell](https://github.com/Shougo/vimshell.vim), but this is not the problem here.

Comment: I meant the complete procedure I described above. You mean that the output of VimScript command is echoed even when in a function which you call through `:silent call`??

Comment: Because, in case it is not clear, if you create a function that echo stuff to screen, enter `:redir @b`, `:silent call MyFunc()` and `:redir end` you end up with no messages on the screen and the entire output of MyFunc() on @b (register b). At least it is what I see here -- I didn't tested this on Linux.